# DRF How to parse text field and serialize result to set of models

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have next models in `models.py`

```
class Rule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField(default='')
    answer = models.TextField(default='')
    rules = models.TextField(default='') # here I decided to store rules names only, separated by coma
```

I have next serializers in `serializers.py`

```
class RuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Rule
        fields = ['name', 'description']


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question', 'answer', 'rules']
```

as result output I have next JSON

```
[
    {
        "question": "How are you?",
        "answer": "fine",
        "rules": "rule 1, rule 2, rule 3"
    }
]
```

but how can I convert `rules` string to objects? I found one solution, but it is means I should convert/serialize `Rule` manually

```
class RuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Rule
        fields = ['name', 'description']


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rules = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question', 'answer', 'rules']
    
    def get_rules(self, obj):
        names = [name.strip() for name in obj.rules.split(",")]
        rules = Rule.objects.all().filter(name__in=names)
        return [{
            "name": rule.name, 
            "description": rule.description,
        } for rule in rules]
```

And of course I can do it manually, but how to do it with already existing serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_rules(self, obj):
        names = [name.strip() for name in obj.rules.split(",")]
        rules = Rule.objects.all().filter(name__in=names)
        
        serializer = RuleSerializer(rules)
        serializer.is_valid() # Mandatory

        return serializer.data
```